# Choosing the right file format

Tags: java, file, serialization, format, file-format

I am working on an application, that should have the possibility to save/load data. Most of the data is stored in instances of a class. The data in the instances consist of:

- a `double[][]` array
- some `String, int, bool` and some enumerators

I have multiple of those instances + some global data that I want to store in a single file.

So far I save all of it as binary data, using

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(FileOutputStream(file));
out.writeInt()/writeBoolean()/writeUTF()/etc
```

This works good, the problem is that it is not very flexible. If I add/remove some variables to my container class, there is no simple way to still have the old format be compatible. I started using a version number that I add at the start of the file. But this results in a big loadData/closeData method for every format version.

Text based files are out of the question, because they use way too much space for my double array.

Do you know a good way to solve this problem? I.e. define a backward compatible format that does not result in a huge amount of code? Any suggestions are appreciated.

An idea that I am thinking of is to mark every variable with an integer identifying that variable. So the format would be `[identifier1][variable1(String)][identifier2][variable2(double[][])]...`.

I also thought of serialization, but I don't have any experience and can not really tell if that is the right way to do it.

Please comment if you need more information about the data or some examples.

Comment: "I started using a version number that I add at the start of the file", you mean serialVersionUID ?

Comment: @GuilhermeTorresCastro No, I don't use serialization yet, just some integer, that I increase every time I change something in the file format.

Comment: @brimborium it won't work, which is why I deleted my initial comment. I think it might be easier for you to serialize each of the variables in the class separately and index those chunks with, e.g., variable names

Comment: this will probably mean writing a huge switch(variableName) { ... }, though, since you'd have to cast each one to the appropriate type, though this can be partially automated using reflection mechanism

Comment: @Qnan at least it would he just one method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/ is Google's nice cross-platform (and cross-language) way of storing data, with backwards compatibility already baked in, could give it a try.

In particular this part of the documentation pertains to your case:

> New fields could be easily introduced, and intermediate servers that didn't need to inspect the data could simply parse it and pass through the data without needing to know about all the fields.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, that sounds like a valid possibility. Although I am a little bit sceptical about the step with the protocol buffer compiler. But hey, google uses it, so it can't be that bad. ;)

Comment: It's actually a really good library, the only reason I never used it is cause .NET provides comparable functionality (for my needs) already baked in its framework library. Read a lot about it though and I can say with certainty I'd use it if I had to program in C++ again.

Comment: I am quite happy with protobuff (although I don't like the additional compilation step). Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

How about some sort of local database, like [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org) or [JavaDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html)? Very lightweight, and saves you trouble of marking your variables, allowing for flexible options of retrieving data.

Comment: if the data is to be used only by this same instance of the application, that might be an option

Comment: I thought of that, but I am not such a huge fan of SQL. I think there would be a lot of overhead (code wise, not data wise), more than doing it by myself somehow...

Comment: It doesn't seem there's that many different types of data to save, you could weasel out by writing a handful of helper methods to access the DB (varargs are a huge pain relief for stmt.setObject())

Answer (score 1):

Do not go the serialization path...
It's full of stones and incompatibilities. Once change a data object,everthing is broken. Google protobuf is a very good solution. Used it once in c++

It's a bit of effort to get to known how to configure your file format, but it's worth it for sure.

Comment: Ok, second suggestion towards protobuf. I am definitely looking into that. ;)

Comment: Keep in mind protobuf requires you to compile the .proto file to .java, which can put a kink in your dev cycle, as it requires the protoc program to be installed.  That being said, it's a fast, flexible solution.

Comment: @Matt That's what I actually don't like. But I am almost sure, that there is an eclipse plugin, that does that stuff automatically.

Comment: I've found that nothing will beat custom serialization using DataOutputStream along with writeInt, writeByte, etc.... If you're unsure of the length of something (like a string), you first write the length of the underlying byte array and then the byte array itself.  Deserialization then becomes just a matter of being smart about how you're reading in the data.  Use a record marker of some sort (you'll have to figure out what to use) to mark the end of a record.  So if you add new fields, you put them on the end, and when reading in, pay attention.

Comment: @Matt Yeah, that's what I thought of doing. Although I think it is a lot of effort. That's why I asked for any alternatives. And I got some. I'll let all of you know, what I finally chose to do. ;)

Comment: Serialisation for sure has also it's advantages, but one big advantage of the protobuf approach is its easynes and language ignorance. Define a format once and you can read/write it in C/Java/...(don't know now).

Answer (score 1):

I never had any problem using `Serialization`, there are few things one should take care while using Serialization.

**/////-----------When does Serialization Fails----------------/////**

**-** When an Instance variable is **removed**.

**-** When the **data type** of the Instance variable is changed.

**-** When the **non-static** Instance variable become a **static** Instance variable.

**-** When the **non-transient** Instance variable becomes a **transient** one.

**-** When a class is **moved up or down** in the **hierarchy**.

**-** When a **serialized** class becomes **non-serialized.**

**/////-----------When Serialization is NOT Effected----------------/////**

**-** When Instance variable is **added**.

**-** When the **access-specifier** of the Instance variable is changed.

**-** When the **transient** Instance variable gets converted to **non-transient** Instance variable.

**-** When you **add or remove classes.**

Comment: Thanks for this list. Do you know of any good tutorial on serialization? The ones I have found do not really answer, how to solve the "add/remove instance variable" problem in a backward compatible way.

Comment: Try these links... http://www.kodejava.org/examples/215.html and http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/serializable.html

Comment: Thx for the tutorials. I will take at look at them :)